# Is there an equivalent to spring-boot-starter-test for wildfly-galleon?

Tags: junit, integration-testing, wildfly

In spring it is easy to write junit-integration tests against a running jax-rs Endpoint using spring-boot-starter-test.
Is there something similar when using wildfly-galleon?

Starting the server and waiting some (undefined) time does not seem to be a good option for me (I would like to run the test inside a CI/CD pipeline).

Comment: What about arquillian ?

Comment: To be clear, spring-boot and wildfly-galleon are very different things. WildFly Galleon is used to provision a WildFly container, not create a bootable JAR.